# how can I reset all switches in tableview from CustomCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswitch, custom-cell

I've set a Switch as part of a tableView cell and set up a CustomCell class to deal with the action, the class looks like this

```
class SwitchTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var `switch`: UISwitch!

    var switchAction: ((Bool) -> Void)?

    @IBAction func switchSwitched(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        switchAction?(sender.isOn)
    }
}
```

What I need to do now is to ensure that when one Switch is turned on, all the other Switches in the other rows are turned off. The table rows are loaded like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let thisRow = rowData[indexPath.row]

    switch thisRow.type {
    case .text:
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "textfieldCell", for: indexPath) as? MovingTextFieldTableViewCell else {
            Logger.shared.log(.app, .error, "Could not load TextFieldTableViewCell")
            fatalError()
        }
        cell.textField.textFieldText = thisRow.data as? String
        cell.textField.labelText = thisRow.title
        cell.dataChanged = { text in
            thisRow.saveData(text)
        }
        cell.errorLabel.text = nil
        return cell
    case .switch:
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "switchCell", for: indexPath) as? SwitchTableViewCell else {
            Logger.shared.log(.app, .error, "Could not load SwitchTableViewCell")
            fatalError()
        }
        cell.label.text = thisRow.title
        cell.switch.isOn = thisRow.data as? Bool ?? false
        cell.switchAction = { isOn in
            thisRow.saveData(isOn)
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

There are two types for thisRow in each row (Text/Switch) and the saveData method looks like this

```
func saveData(_ data: Any?) {
    self.data = data
}
```

The table is not updated when the Switch is changed but as the class deals with only one row action at a time, I'm unsure how to update the TableView from the custom Switch class

Comment: What is the data type for `thisRow`? Show that class/struct and the `saveData` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the responsibility of the controller that is setting the `switchAction` of each cell.

When the `switchAction` closure is called, the provider of the closure must update its data model as needed and reload the table view.

You need to update your `switchAction` in `cellForRowAt` to something like this:

```
cell.switchAction = { isOn in
    thisRow.saveData(isOn)

    // This switch is on, reset all of the other row data
    if isOn {
        for (index, row) in rowData.enumerated() {
            if index != indexPath.row && row.type == .switch {
                row.saveData(false)
            }
        }

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```